# Female protagonist in a futuristic army vs. rebels film

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I saw this movie in 1999 or 2000 on TV (when they wouldn't even display names during the movie). It was a futuristic Govt + Army against *rebels* kind of a movie with a female central character. I remember 4 things from the movie

1. The movie wasn't animated but lots of animated scenes were shown in between like Natural Born Killers!
2. Lots of fancy airships and guns.
3. The girl when captured refers to blowjobs as "Anyone needs an oil change"
4. In the final fight scene, an animation is shown where her boobs turn into missiles.

Looked like a hell of a movie but I have never been able to track it! Would appreciate if anyone can help!

Comment: Cross posting is discouraged.  You've posted this exact same question here and on SciFi and Fantasy.  It really should be posted to only one site, not both.

Comment: Dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18288/help-me-identify-this-sci-fi-movie-with-lots-lots-of-animation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds a lot like [Tank Girl](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114614/).

First part of the plot on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tank_Girl_%28film%29) says:

> Set in a dystopian 2033, a comet has hit the Earth, and altered the
>   climate turning it into a dry and arid wasteland. There has been no
>   rain for over 11 years - water is extremely scarce, and what little is
>   available is controlled by the Water & Power company, led by Kesslee
>   (Malcolm McDowell). Water & Power are opposed by the almost mythical
>   "Rippers", a mysterious group that no one can find. Rebecca - Tank
>   Girl - (Lori Petty), is a member of a small community that has set up
>   their own water well in the basement of a house. Learning of this,
>   Water & Power attacks, killing most in the house and capturing Rebecca
>   and a young girl named Sam. Imprisoned, Rebecca is repeatedly
>   brutalized by Kesslee, who wishes to break her spirit, brainwashing
>   her into working for him. Between intellectual jousts with Kesslee,
>   Rebecca befriends Jet Girl (Naomi Watts) - an otherwise un-named
>   mechanic who works on Water & Power's vehicles.

During the movie there are some animated scenes, some of them quite weird.  If I recall correctly one of them matches the [missile thing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8LqnPQEAN0#t=18s).